Frontend developer seeking assistance with large and complex systems
I am a frontend developer working on a highly robust hospital system. We are in the process of migrating its desktop version to the web. However, one significant challenge is the absence of a dedicated designer, which is complicating my work significantly.
I have access to the desktop screens to use as a reference, but they are dated—reminiscent of designs from the early 2000s. At best, they can guide feature implementation. Even so, one of our primary objectives is to improve the user experience, which might require adding new functionalities. Additionally, many of the screens primarily consist of tables accompanied by side or bottom visualizations.
A designer's expertise in user experience and styling would be invaluable. In their absence, I attempted to use Vuetify's design system as a guide. While Material Design (used by Vuetify) has its merits, I find it visually overwhelming—it creates a "solid" aesthetic that doesn’t align with the simplicity I prefer. Personally, I gravitate toward design systems like Apple’s.
To find inspiration, I explored Dribbble and the Figma Community for templates and ideas. However, as I lack advanced proficiency in Figma, designing and coding simultaneously is proving too exhausting. Consequently, I am designing directly in code—a method I wouldn’t recommend.
Given this context, I have two primary questions:

Can I use Apple's design system, or at least draw inspiration from it? (I ask because I understand it may be subject to licensing restrictions.)

Are there any resources or websites where I can find more comprehensive designs for complex systems?



You can mimick Apple's design system. However, you probably shouldn't be. Have you ever seen an interface that looks like one of Apple's in a hospital? There's good reason for that: hospitals interfaces are meant to be easy to skim, help people who use them regularly be very efficient, and minimize potentially life-ending mistakes, not to mention the legal requirements for them. Effectively there's no hope for you to design a good system by yourself without intimate knowledge of their needs and requirements
